# Filter vector inside MutexGuard without cloning

Tags: rust, mutex

I have a locked `a` with a vecotr of `B` struct inside. I'd like to filter `a.b` without cloning `B` struct. Is it possible in Rust?

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct B {
    n: i64,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct A {
    b: Vec<B>
}

fn main() {
    let arc_a = Arc::new(Mutex::new(A {
        b: vec![
            B { n: 1 },
            B { n: 2 },
            B { n: 3 },
            B { n: 4 },
        ]
    }));
    let mut a = arc_a.lock().unwrap();
    a.b = a.b.into_iter().filter(|b| b.n % 2 == 1).collect();
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

In the code example above I have an error `error[E0507]: cannot move out of dereference of MutexGuard<'_, A>`. Are there ways to solve this challenge? How to solve it correctly?

Comment: Do you need the filter to produce owned `B`s, or will `&B`s be enough?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman `&B` is enough, I can change the type